# Possible to use a column name in a UDF in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-functions

I have a query in which a series of steps is repeated constantly over different columns, for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       MAX (
          CASE
             WHEN table_2."GRP1_MINIMUM_DATE" <= cohort."ANCHOR_DATE" THEN 1
             ELSE 0
          END)
       OVER (PARTITION BY cohort."USER_ID")
          AS "GRP1_MINIMUM_DATE",
       MAX (
          CASE
             WHEN table_2."GRP2_MINIMUM_DATE" <= cohort."ANCHOR_DATE" THEN 1
             ELSE 0
          END)
       OVER (PARTITION BY cohort."USER_ID")
          AS "GRP2_MINIMUM_DATE"
  FROM INPUT_COHORT cohort
       LEFT JOIN INVOLVE_EVER table_2 ON cohort."USER_ID" = table_2."USER_ID"
```

I was considering writing a function to accomplish this as doing so would save on space in my query. I have been reading a bit about UDF in SQL but don't yet understand if it is possible to pass a column name in as a parameter (i.e. simply switch out "GRP1_MINIMUM_DATE" for "GRP2_MINIMUM_DATE" etc.). What I would like is a query which looks like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
FUNCTION(table_2."GRP1_MINIMUM_DATE") AS "GRP1_MINIMUM_DATE",
FUNCTION(table_2."GRP2_MINIMUM_DATE") AS "GRP2_MINIMUM_DATE",
FUNCTION(table_2."GRP3_MINIMUM_DATE") AS "GRP3_MINIMUM_DATE",
FUNCTION(table_2."GRP4_MINIMUM_DATE") AS "GRP4_MINIMUM_DATE" 
FROM INPUT_COHORT cohort
       LEFT JOIN INVOLVE_EVER table_2 ON cohort."USER_ID" = table_2."USER_ID"
```

Can anyone tell me if this is possible/point me to some resource that might help me out here?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such direct way but yes you can achieve it using PL/SQL's dynamic query concept.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such direct as @Tejash already stated, but the thing looks like your database model is not ideal - it would be better to have a table that has `USER_ID` and `GRP_ID` as keys and then `MINIMUM_DATE` as seperate field.

Without changing the table structure, you can use `UNPIVOT` query to mimic this design:

```
WITH INVOLVE_EVER(USER_ID, GRP1_MINIMUM_DATE, GRP2_MINIMUM_DATE, GRP3_MINIMUM_DATE, GRP4_MINIMUM_DATE)
  AS (SELECT 1, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, SYSDATE FROM dual UNION ALL 
      SELECT 2, SYSDATE-1, SYSDATE-2, SYSDATE-3, SYSDATE-4 FROM dual)
SELECT * 
  FROM INVOLVE_EVER
  unpivot ( minimum_date FOR grp_id IN ( GRP1_MINIMUM_DATE AS 1, GRP2_MINIMUM_DATE AS 2, GRP3_MINIMUM_DATE AS 3, GRP4_MINIMUM_DATE AS 4))
```

Result:

```
| USER_ID | GRP_ID | MINIMUM_DATE |
|---------|--------|--------------|
|    1    |    1   | 09/09/19     |
|    1    |    2   | 09/09/19     |
|    1    |    3   | 09/09/19     |
|    1    |    4   | 09/09/19     |
|    2    |    1   | 09/08/19     |
|    2    |    2   | 09/07/19     |
|    2    |    3   | 09/06/19     |
|    2    |    4   | 09/05/19     |
```

With this you can write your query without further code duplication and if you need use `PIVOT`-syntax to get one line per `USER_ID`.

The final query could then look like this:

```
WITH INVOLVE_EVER(USER_ID, GRP1_MINIMUM_DATE, GRP2_MINIMUM_DATE, GRP3_MINIMUM_DATE, GRP4_MINIMUM_DATE)
  AS (SELECT 1, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, SYSDATE FROM dual UNION ALL 
      SELECT 2, SYSDATE-1, SYSDATE-2, SYSDATE-3, SYSDATE-4 FROM dual)
   , INPUT_COHORT(USER_ID, ANCHOR_DATE) 
  AS (SELECT 1, SYSDATE-1 FROM dual UNION ALL 
      SELECT 2, SYSDATE-2 FROM dual UNION ALL 
      SELECT 3, SYSDATE-3 FROM dual)
-- Above is sampledata query starts from here:
   , unpiv AS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INVOLVE_EVER
               unpivot ( minimum_date FOR grp_id IN ( GRP1_MINIMUM_DATE AS 1, GRP2_MINIMUM_DATE AS 2, GRP3_MINIMUM_DATE AS 3, GRP4_MINIMUM_DATE AS 4)))
SELECT qcsj_c000000001000000 user_id, GRP1_MINIMUM_DATE, GRP2_MINIMUM_DATE, GRP3_MINIMUM_DATE, GRP4_MINIMUM_DATE
  FROM INPUT_COHORT cohort
  LEFT JOIN unpiv table_2
    ON cohort.USER_ID = table_2.USER_ID
pivot (MAX(CASE WHEN minimum_date <= cohort."ANCHOR_DATE" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MINIMUM_DATE
 FOR grp_id IN (1 AS GRP1,2 AS GRP2,3 AS GRP3,4 AS GRP4))
```

Result:

```
| USER_ID | GRP1_MINIMUM_DATE | GRP2_MINIMUM_DATE | GRP3_MINIMUM_DATE | GRP4_MINIMUM_DATE |
|---------|-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
| 3       |                   |                   |                   |                   |
| 1       | 0                 | 0                 | 0                 | 0                 |
| 2       | 0                 | 1                 | 1                 | 1                 |
```

This way you only have to write your calculation logic once (see line starting with `pivot`).